# Text-Based RPG Dungeon Game in Java

Tags: java, object-oriented, role-playing-game

I'm trying to follow as many OO concepts as possible.  This project is for my github, as a means to enhance my portfolio for possible internships in the future.

Question 1: Is there anything that's declared static that shouldn't be?

Question 2: Should I have created a constructor for the Dungeon class, that way each dungeon is its own instance instead of have a factory make it every time?

Some notes about the program:

I generate a 30x30 array of Room objects, which also randomly generate a random monster in each room. As of now, the player can select new game, and pick a character. From there, they spawn in the middle room [14][14] where they fight each monster and can move room to room.

Any general tips or advice about the code of the program would be greatly appreciated!

### ProjectMoria class:

```
package projectmoria;


import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner; //needed for user_input

public class ProjectMoria {

    public static final Scanner USERINPUT = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static final Random RAND = new Random();
    public static Room[][] currDungeon;
    public static Player currPlayer;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        mainMenu();
    }

    public static void mainMenu() {
        boolean status = false;
        do {
            IO.Welcome();
            String selection = USERINPUT.nextLine();
            switch (selection) {
                case "1":
                    newGame();
                    status = true;
                    break;
                case "2":
                    loadGame();
                    status = true;
                    break;
                case "3":
                    settings();
                    status = true;
                    break;
                case "4":
                    IO.credits();
                    status = true;
                    break;
                case "5":
                    System.exit(0);
            }

        } while (status == false);

    }

    public static void newGame() {
        Dungeon dungeon = new Dungeon();
        boolean status = false;
        do {
            IO.newGameIntroduction();
            String selection = USERINPUT.nextLine();
            switch (selection) {
                case "1":
                    status = IO.displayPlayerStats("Warrior", "A tough, "
                            + "well-rounded fighter with a balanced skillset.",
                            100, 20, 30, 3, 0.10);
                    currPlayer = Player.newWarrior();

                    break;
                case "2":
                    status = IO.displayPlayerStats("Dueler", "A quick, nimble "
                            + "duelist with an aptitude for landing critical "
                            + "attacks.", 80, 10, 50, 2, 0.18);
                    currPlayer = Player.newDuelist();

                    break;
            }
        } while (status == false);

        currDungeon = Dungeon.newRandomDungeon(currPlayer);
        dungeon.dungeonLogic(currPlayer, currDungeon);

    }

    public static void loadGame() {

    }

    public static void settings() {

    }

}
```

### Dungeon class:

```
package projectmoria;


public final class Dungeon {

    private static boolean northDirection = false;
    private static boolean southDirection = false;
    private static boolean westDirection = false;
    private static boolean eastDirection = false;

    public static Room[][] newRandomDungeon(Player player) {
        Room[][] dungeon = new Room[30][30];
        for (int i = 0; i < dungeon.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < dungeon.length; j++) {
                dungeon[i][j] = Room.newRoomInstance();

            }
        }
        player.setCurrRoom(dungeon[14][14]);
        return dungeon;
    }

    public boolean roomExists(int x, int y) {
        return  (rowExists(x)) && (colExists(y));
    }

    public boolean rowExists(int x){
        return  (x >= 0) && (x <= 29);
    }

    public boolean colExists(int y){
        return  (y >= 0) && (y <= 29);
    }

    public void playerMovement(Player player) {
        northDirection = roomExists(player.getCurrX(), player.getCurrY()
                + 1);
        southDirection = roomExists(player.getCurrX(), player.getCurrY()
                - 1);
        eastDirection = roomExists(player.getCurrX() + 1,
                player.getCurrY());
        westDirection = roomExists(player.getCurrX() - 1,
                player.getCurrY());
        IO.movePlayer(player);

    }

    public void battle(Player player, Monster monster, Room[][] dungeon) {
        IO.battleIntro(player, dungeon[player.getCurrX()][player.getCurrY()]);
        IO.battle(player, monster);
    }

    public void dungeonLogic(Player player, Room[][] dungeon) {
        while (player.isAlive()) {
            if (player.isAlive() && dungeon[player.getCurrX()][player.getCurrY()]
                    .getMonster().isAlive()) {
                battle(player, dungeon[player.getCurrX()][player.getCurrY()]
                        .getMonster(), ProjectMoria.currDungeon);
            } else if (player.isAlive()) {
                playerMovement(player);
            }
        }
    }

    public static boolean isNorthDirection() {
        return northDirection;
    }

    public static boolean isSouthDirection() {
        return southDirection;
    }

    public static boolean isWestDirection() {
        return westDirection;
    }

    public static boolean isEastDirection() {
        return eastDirection;
    }

}
```

### IO class:

```
package projectmoria;

import java.io.*;

public final class IO {

    public static void playerCrit() {
        System.out.println("Nice! You landed a critical hit! (x2 Damage)");
    }

    public static void monsterCrit() {
        System.out.println("Ouch! The monster landed a critical hit! "
                + "(x2 Damage)");
    }

    public static void Welcome() {
        System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"
                + "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
        System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"
                + "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
        System.out.println("Welcome traveler.......");
        System.out.println("To the mines of Moria! ");
        System.out.println("-----------------------");
        System.out.println("       MAIN MENU       ");
        System.out.println("_______________________");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(" 1.      New Game        ");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(" 2.     Load Game        ");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(" 3.      Settings        ");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(" 4.       Credits        ");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(" 5.     Exit Game        ");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print(" Make a Selection: ");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void newGameIntroduction() {
        System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"
                + "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
        System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"
                + "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
        System.out.println("------------------");
        System.out.println("CHOOSE A CHARACTER");
        System.out.println("------------------");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("1. WARRI0R");
        System.out.println("----------");
        System.out.println("A tough, well-rounded fighter with"
                + " a balanced skillset.");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("2. DUELIST");
        System.out.println("----------");
        System.out.println("A quick, nimble duelist with an"
                + "aptitude for landing critical attacks.");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("________________________");
        System.out.print("Choose Either Character: ");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static boolean displayPlayerStats(String name, String description,
            int maxHitPoints, int minDamage, int maxDamage, int defense,
            double critChance) {
        System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"
                + "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
        System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"
                + "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
        System.out.println(name);
        System.out.println("-------");
        System.out.println(description);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("MAX HP: " + maxHitPoints);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(
                "ATTACK: " + minDamage + "-" + maxDamage);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("DEFENSE(Scale:1-5): " + defense);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("CRIT CHANCE: " + critChance + "%");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("ARE YOU SURE YOU WANT TO PLAY AS A "
                + name.toUpperCase() + "? "
                + "(y/n)");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        if (ProjectMoria.USERINPUT.nextLine().equals("y")) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void credits() {
        System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"
                + "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
        System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"
                + "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
        System.out.println("This game was created by Jackson Kolb.");
        System.out.println("Would you like to return to the main menu? (y/n)");
        if (ProjectMoria.USERINPUT.nextLine().equals("y")) {
            ProjectMoria.mainMenu();
        }
    }

    public static void movePlayer(Player player) {

        if (Dungeon.isNorthDirection() == true) {
            System.out.println("North (n)\n");
        }
        if (Dungeon.isSouthDirection() == true) {
            System.out.println("South (s)\n");
        }
        if (Dungeon.isEastDirection() == true) {
            System.out.println("East (e)\n");
        }
        if (Dungeon.isWestDirection() == true) {
            System.out.println("West (w)\n");
        }

        System.out.print("Where would you like to travel?: ");
        String selection = ProjectMoria.USERINPUT.nextLine();
        if (selection.equals("n") && Dungeon.isNorthDirection()) {
            player.setCurrY(player.getCurrY() + 1);
        } else if (selection.equals("s") && Dungeon.isSouthDirection()) {
            player.setCurrY(player.getCurrY() - 1);
        } else if (selection.equals("e") && Dungeon.isEastDirection()) {
            player.setCurrX(player.getCurrX() + 1);
        } else if (selection.equals("w") && Dungeon.isWestDirection()) {
            player.setCurrX(player.getCurrX() - 1);
        }

    }

    public static void battleIntro(Player player, Room room) {
        System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"
                + "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
        System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"
                + "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
        System.out.println("You arrive at Room [" + player.getCurrX() + "]["
                + player.getCurrY() + "]");
        System.out.println("You enter the room and look around and see...");
        System.out.println(room.getDescription() + "\n\n");
        System.out.println("Number of monsters: " + room.getNumOfMonsters());
        System.out.println("Your fight with " + room.getMonster().getName()
                + " begins.\n");
    }

    public static void battle(Player player, Monster monster) {
        while (player.isAlive() && monster.isAlive()) {
            System.out.println("\nMonster HP: " + monster.getHitPoints()
                    + "    " + "Player HP: " + player.getHitPoints());
            System.out.println("----------------------------------");
            System.out.print("\nAttack (a)   Heal (h)");
            String action = ProjectMoria.USERINPUT.nextLine();
            if (action.equals("a")) {
                monster.defend(player);
                if (monster.isAlive()) {
                    player.defend(monster);
                }
            } 
        }
        if (!player.isAlive()) {
            System.out.println("Your lifeless body hits the floor.  GAME OVER");
        } else if (!monster.isAlive()) {
            System.out.println("The monster has been defeated!");
            System.out.println("--------------------------------\n");
        }

    }

    public static void playerHitPointsMessage(int damage, Monster monster) {
        System.out.println("The " + monster.getName() + " hit you for "
                + damage + " damage.");
    }

    public static void monsterHitPointsMessage(int damage, Monster monster) {
        System.out.println("You hit the " + monster.getName()
                + " for " + damage + " damage.");
    }

}
```

### Player class:

```
package projectmoria;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Player {

    private final String name;
    private final String description;
    private final int maxHitPoints;
    private int hitPoints;
    private final int minDamage;
    private final int maxDamage;
    private final int defense;
    private double critChance;
    private int currX;
    private int currY;
    private Room currRoom;
    private List<Item> inventory;

    public Player(String name, String description, int maxHitPoints,
            int minDamage, int maxDamage, int defense, double critChance) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.maxHitPoints = maxHitPoints;
        this.hitPoints = maxHitPoints;
        this.minDamage = minDamage;
        this.maxDamage = maxDamage;
        this.defense = defense;
        this.critChance = critChance;
        this.currX = 14;
        this.currY = 14;
        inventory = new ArrayList<>();

    }

    public int attack() {
        return ProjectMoria.RAND.nextInt(maxDamage - minDamage + 1);
    }

    public int defend(Monster monster) {
        int incomingAttack = monster.attack();
        int random = ProjectMoria.RAND.nextInt(99) + 1;
        if (random <= monster.getCritChance()) {
            incomingAttack = incomingAttack * 2;
            IO.monsterCrit(); //TODO - move to different spot
        }
        IO.playerHitPointsMessage(incomingAttack, monster);
        hitPoints = (hitPoints * defense > incomingAttack)
                ? hitPoints - incomingAttack : 0;
        return hitPoints;
    }

    public void heal(Item potion){
        this.hitPoints =+ 20;
        inventory.remove(potion);
        IO.heal(this.hitPoints);
    }

    public static Player newWarrior() {
        return new Player("Warrior", "A tough, well-rounded fighter with"
                + " a balanced skillset.", 100, 20, 30, 3, 10);
    }

    public static Player newDuelist() {
        return new Player("Duelist", "A quick, nimble duelist with an"
                + " aptitude for landing critical attacks.", 8000, 10, 50, 2, 
                18);
    }

     public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public int getHitPoints() {
        return hitPoints;
    }

    public boolean isAlive() {
        return hitPoints > 0;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getMaxHitPoints() {
        return maxHitPoints;
    }

    public int getMinDamage() {
        return minDamage;
    }

    public int getMaxDamage() {
        return maxDamage;
    }

    public int getDefense() {
        return defense;
    }

    public double getCritChance() {
        return critChance;
    }

    public int getCurrX() {
        return currX;
    }

    public int getCurrY() {
        return currY;
    }

    public List<Item> getInventory() {
        return inventory;
    }


    public Room getCurrRoom() {
        return currRoom;
    }

    public void setCurrRoom(Room room) {
        currRoom = room;
    }

    public void setCurrX(int currX) {
        this.currX = currX;
    }

    public void setCurrY(int currY) {
        this.currY = currY;
    }
}
```

### Monster class:

```
package projectmoria;

import java.util.Random;

public class Monster {

    private final String name;
    private final String description;
    private final int maxHitPoints;
    private int hitPoints;
    private final int minDamage;
    private final int maxDamage;
    private final int defense;
    private final double critChance;
    private boolean aggression;
    private static final Random rand = new Random();

    public Monster(String name, String description, int maxHitPoints,
            int minDamage, int maxDamage, int defense, double critChance,
            boolean aggression) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.maxHitPoints = maxHitPoints;
        this.hitPoints = maxHitPoints;
        this.minDamage = minDamage;
        this.maxDamage = maxDamage;
        this.defense = defense;
        this.critChance = critChance;
        this.aggression = aggression;
    }

    public int attack() {
        return rand.nextInt(maxDamage - minDamage - 1);
    }

    public int defend(Player player) {
        int incomingAttack = player.attack();
        int random = rand.nextInt(99) + 1;
        if (random <= player.getCritChance()) {
            incomingAttack = incomingAttack * 2;
            IO.playerCrit();
        }
        IO.monsterHitPointsMessage(incomingAttack, this);
        hitPoints = (hitPoints * defense > incomingAttack)
                ? hitPoints - incomingAttack : 0;
        return hitPoints;
    }

    public static Monster newRandomMonster() {
        int random = rand.nextInt(4) + 1;
        Monster monster = null;
        switch (random) {
            case 1:
                monster = newGoblin();
                break;
            case 2:
                monster = newOrc();
                break;
            case 3:
                monster = newShadowAssassin();
                break;
            case 4:
                monster = newFeralGhoul();
                break;
        }
        return monster;
    }

    public static Monster newGoblin() {
        return new Monster("Goblin", "A grotesque, small enemy with a sub-par "
                + "skill-set. ", 30, 10, 15, 2, 10, true);
    }

    public static Monster newOrc() {
        return new Monster("Orc", "A brutish, green mass of destruction. High "
                + "Attack and Defense.", 50, 15, 20, 3, 10, true);
    }

    public static Monster newDragon() {
        return new Monster("Dragon", "A massive scaled wivern.  I hope you "
                + "brought some potions..", 100, 20, 30, 4, 11, true);
    }

    public static Monster newShadowAssassin() {
        return new Monster("Shadow Assassin", "A dark, elusive assassin trained"
                + " to land critical hits.  Low HP, with high attack.", 20, 15,
                35, 2, 20, true);
    }

    public static Monster newGhoul() {
        return new Monster("Ghoul", "A humaniod exposed to radiation, but still"
                + " maintains a consciousness.  Can be aggressive in certain "
                + "situations.", 40, 10, 25, 2, 8, false);
    }

    public static Monster newFeralGhoul() {
        return new Monster("Feral Ghoul", "A humaniod exposed to radiation, so "
                + "much that it can't distinguish friend from foe.",
                40, 10, 25, 2, 8, true);
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public int getHitPoints() {
        return hitPoints;
    }

    public boolean isAlive() {
        return hitPoints > 0;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + " " + description;
    }

    public double getCritChance() {
        return critChance;
    }
}
```

### Room class:

```
package projectmoria;

public final class Room {

    private final String description;
    private final Monster monster;
    private final int numOfMonsters;
    private final boolean isBossRoom;
    //private final boolean lighting;

    private Room(String description, Monster monster, boolean isBossRoom,
            int numOfMonsters) {
        this.description = description;
        this.monster = monster;
        //this.lighting = lighting;
        this.isBossRoom = isBossRoom;
        this.numOfMonsters = numOfMonsters;
    }

    public static Room newRoomInstance() {
        String description = null;
        int numOfMonsters = 0;
        //boolean lighting = true;
        boolean isBossRoom = false;
        int random = ProjectMoria.RAND.nextInt(3) + 1; //Change random value parameter to add more room types
        switch (random) {
            case 1:
                description = "A dark corridor with creeping, animated vines.";
                numOfMonsters = 1;
                //lighting = false;
                break;
            case 2:
                description = "A single lantern lays on the floor, illuminating"
                        + " a skeleton of a past explorer. Two pairs of eyes "
                        + "can be seen.";
                numOfMonsters = 1;
                //lighting = true;
                break;
            case 3:
                description = "A green, floral room full of massive plants.";
                numOfMonsters = 1;
                //lighting = true;
                break;
            /*case 4:
                    description = "a giant dragon";
                    numOfMonsters = 1;
                    isBossRoom = true;
                    break;      
                case 5:
                    description = "";
                    numOfMonsters = 1;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    description = "";
                    numOfMonsters = 1;
                    break;
                case 7:
                    description = "";
                    numOfMonsters = 1;
                    break;
                case 8:
                    description = "";
                    numOfMonsters = 1;
                    break;
                case 9:
                    description = "";
                    numOfMonsters = 1;
                    break;
                case 10:
                    description = "";
                    numOfMonsters = 1;
                    break;*/
        }
        return new Room(description, Monster.newRandomMonster(), false,
                numOfMonsters);

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return description;
    }

    public boolean isBossRoom() {
        return isBossRoom;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public Monster getMonster() {
        return monster;
    }

    public int getNumOfMonsters() {
        return numOfMonsters;
    }

    public boolean isIsBossRoom() {
        return isBossRoom;
    }

}
```

### Item class:

```
package projectmoria;

public class Item {

    private final String name;
    private final String type;
    private final String description;

    public Item(String name, String type, String description) {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public void use(Player player, Item item) {
        if (item.type.equals("Potion")) {
            player.heal(item);
        }
    }

    public static void addPotion(int numOfPotions, Player player) {
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfPotions; i++) {
            player.getInventory().add(potion());
        }
    }

    private static Item potion() {
        return new Item("Potion", "Potion", " a small vial filled with a " + "translucent red liquid");
    }
}
```

Comment: is this hosted somewhere?

Comment: @RE60K Im sorry, I'm kind of new to some jargon.  Do you mean to ask if I have the current version added to a website somewhere? If so, I do have it up on my github, for version control.

Comment: Yes I meant that, it would be easy to clone that and try running.

Comment: https://github.com/JacksonKolb94/ProjectMoria

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The biggest issue I see with your code is your ability to extend it effectively. I would recomend you store a lot of you data in a format like [JSON](http://json.org/). So you could create for a `Monster` something like:

```
{
  "name" : "Ooogle",
  "attack" : 20,
  "defense" : 30,
  ...
}, 
{
  "name" : "Argle",
  "attack" : 31,
  "defense" : 20
  ...
},
```

There actually may be is a better way to represent this with JSON. I'm not a JSON expert. The point I'm trying to make is this will help clean up a lot monster creation code, and room creation that looks like this:

```
    switch (random) {
        case 1:
            description = "A dark corridor with creeping, animated vines.";
            numOfMonsters = 1;
            //lighting = false;
            break;
        case 2:
            description = "A single lantern lays on the floor, illuminating"
                    + " a skeleton of a past explorer. Two pairs of eyes "
                    + "can be seen.";
            numOfMonsters = 1;
            //lighting = true;
            break;
        case 3:
            description = "A green, floral room full of massive plants.";
            numOfMonsters = 1;
            //lighting = true;
            break;
        /*case 4:
                description = "a giant dragon";
                numOfMonsters = 1;
                isBossRoom = true;
                break;      
            case 5:
                description = "";
                numOfMonsters = 1;
                break;
            case 6:
                description = "";
                numOfMonsters = 1;
                break;
            case 7:
                description = "";
                numOfMonsters = 1;
                break;
            case 8:
                description = "";
                numOfMonsters = 1;
                break;
            case 9:
                description = "";
                numOfMonsters = 1;
                break;
            case 10:
                description = "";
                numOfMonsters = 1;
                break;*/
```

There might be even better ways than JSON, but it is definitely a push in the right direction as it isolates the data models from your code.

Comment: After doing a little reading on JSON (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383692/what-is-json-and-why-would-i-use-it), It looks like it's a universal short hand language based on javascript.  Like xml if it was skinnier. What would that accomplish for my swing statements?  Should i create a JSON file seperately, and then read from it?  Thank you!

Comment: You should write a JSON file and read from it. As for the switch statements, I don't know the exact syntax in Java but you can randomly select a JSON entry and inject that data into an object. In otherwords, don't do a bunch of case statments, just access a random element in JSON.

Answer (score 3):

There is NO `heal()` method in class `IO`...